# OpenGL: fastest way to draw 2d image

Tags: opengl

I am writing an interactive path tracer and I was wondering what is the best way to draw the result on screen in modern GL. I have the result of the rendering stored in a pixel buffer that is updated on each pass (+1 ssp). And I would like to draw it on screen after each pass. I did some searching and people have suggested drawing a textured quad for displaying 2d images. Does that mean I would create a new texture each time I update? And given that my pixels are updated very frequently, is this still a good idea?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to create an entirely new texture every time you want to update the content. If the size stays the same, you can reserve the storage once, using `glTexImage2D()` with NULL as the last argument. E.g. for a 512x512 RGBA texture with 8-bit component precision:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 512, 512, 0,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

In OpenGL 4.2 and later, you can also use:

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA8, 512, 512);
```

You can then update all or parts of the texture with `glTexSubImage2D()`. For example, to update the whole texture following the example above:

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 512, 512,
                GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Of course, if only rectangular part(s) of the texture change each time, you can make the updates more selective by choosing the 2nd to 5th parameter accordingly.

Once your current data is in a texture, you can either draw a textured screen size quad, or copy the texture to the default framebuffer using `glBlitFramebuffer()`. You should be able to find plenty of sample code for the first option. The code for the second option would look something like this:

```
// One time during setup.
GLuint readFboId = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &readFboId);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, readFboId);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

// Every time you want to copy the texture to the default framebuffer.
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, readFboId);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, texWidth, texHeight,
                  0, 0, winWidth, winHeight,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Question, in your example, where does 'tex' come from? Is it like 'data' above?

Comment: Would be nice to create a gist